# Use Built-in Android Face detection as an input for recognition

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, built-in

Is it possible to use the built-in android face detection as an input for recognition? I was going through some articles online and i have found out that the built-in face detection on Android has better result than the one made with open cv or java cv. I want to do recognition and i was wondering if its possible to give the output of the built-in face detection as an input for Recognition.If thats possible can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: download the zip file here http://www.mediafire.com/download/f184lcnepjc0fnz/facedetect.zip

Comment: Thanks for the response.First of all the code only displays a picture and nothing else happens like that is stopped or something.Ans my question is can i use this built in code as an input for face recognition. My question is not really about how to do face detection on Android using the built-in Android.media.FaceDetector API.Can I USE THIS In-BUILT FACE DETECTOR API AS AN INPUT FOR FACE RECOGNITION.Thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: you need to add refrence API like this https://www.mashape.com/lambda/face-recognition#!documentation

Comment: That looks quite interesting. I will go through and let you know my response.Thankyou very much!!!